# Is it possible to deploy ASP.NET MVC to a .NET 2.0 server?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq-to-sql, .net-2.0, linqbridge

I have a win 2k3 server (so stating the obvious IIS6) with service pack 2. Is it possible to bin deploy an ASP.NET MVC 2 application to this server with installing additional material on the server? The server currently has .NET 2.0 framework installed, but there is too much red tape to upgrade the server.

I have found an article from Scott Hanselman stating that pre-official MVC 1 release can operate on .NET 2.0 framework provided you do not use .NET 3.5 features (i.e. LINQ). However further research shows that LINQBridge supports .NET 2.0 framework.

Is it possible to combine these technologies to deploy an ASP.NET MVC application to a .NET 2.0 server?

Comment: Question?  Why would you want to?

Comment: because once you have the correct framework installed, it's really pretty easy to do a bin deployment of an mvc application to Server 2003. at least, with .net 4.0 it was.

Comment: @JohnHartsock I would love to properly use .NET 3.5 (4 even), unfortunately I have no control over the production server

Comment: @James...  Well if your wanting to use MVC then I would suggest putting in that request for .Net 3.5 sp1 or higher to be installed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it is not possible. ASP.NET MVC 2 has a dependency on the `System.Core` assembly which is .NET 3.5 or higher. Sorry. Time to upgrade the box. Simply install .NET 4.0 or .NET 3.5 on the server and make your application run. And when you are ready to upgrade shoot for ASP.NET MVC 3.0. And of course if this takes time and ASP.NET MVC 4.0 is out shoot for it.

.NET 2.0 just like .NET 1.1 is history that we should leave in the past as fast as possible if we want to progress.

Comment: Any reason for the downvote? If you think that the answer is wrong please leave a comment when downvoting.

Comment: The question specifically states that upgrading the server is not an option.

Comment: @dsteele, and the answer explicitly states that you cannot run ASP.NET MVC 2 application on .NET 2.0. Me too I want a Ferrari but I can't afford it. So if the OP cannot upgrade to at least .NET 3.5 it means that he cannot afford to run an ASP.NET MVC 2 application on this server. It's as simple as that.

Comment: at least installing the newest framework isn't too big of a hassle since they can all run side by side.

Comment: @DarinDimitrov I understand MVC 2 may not work, but I did find http://www.hanselman.com/blog/DeployingASPNETMVCOnASPNET20.aspx I was wondering if anyone had success using this method as there are very little additional references to such a work around on the net.

Comment: @James, I would really recommend you to spend your time with more useful things than trying to do this.